# How to use different labels in one for cycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop

ex: label[i].text. in

```
int r = GridView1.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
{
    Label[i]+"1".text="something";   
}
```

Here, in one `for` cycle, I want to fill different labels. Label id's are Label01, Label02,Label03 and so on. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Label myLabel = this.FindControl("Label"+i+"1") as Label; 
myLabel.Text = "my text";
```

THIS should solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

If you can 'predict' the Id of the Label then you can find it:

```
int r = GridView1.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
{
     string id = "baseName" + i;  // your naming scheme
     var lbl = (Label) this.FindControl(id);
     lbl.text="something";   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add all the labels into a `List<Label>` or `SortedList<Label>` and iterate over that.

```
var labels = new SortedList<Label>();
lables.Add("Lable01", Label01);
lables.Add("Lable02", Label02);
...

int r = GridView1.Rows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
{
     lables["Label" + i.ToString("00")].text = "somthing";
}
```

There are no [control arrays](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-control-array-tutorial) in .NET, as there were in VB6.